# Printing contents contained in hortizonal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, printing, scrollbar

I am using http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/ and have a requirement to be able to print everything contained within the scrollbar, I don't want to scale down the contents onto one page but rather print on multiple pages.

I was wondering if anyone knew of potential solutions for printing contents in a scroll bar? I did try applying a print style sheet but didn't have much luck.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: Do you mean you want to print what is in the content window even when the content is so wide that it scrolls sideways?

Comment: I suppose it could be quite possible with some `JS` or `jQuery`. Is that a reasonable solution? I'd imagine you'd need some `client-side` script to determine their `window width` and `height` at the time of printing.

Comment: Do you have a link to your app? I was thinking along lines of:
print->use jquery to press advance right button->print and repeat OR possibly to override the gantt chart, exposing the wide table underneath, then printing that. If you have a link or code, would be helpful.